# Image shows correctly in network "Preview" but on its response.data it's all broken gibberish

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, multer

My issue is the following

Inside `/uploads/{userid}/` there is a single image I named `user-pf.png`, I can access that folder just right and retrieve the image from it, but my frontend doesn't display it properly, even though it can "see" the image just right, as images below will show.

This is the code I have on my frontend (REACT) and my backend (NodeJS)

```
import api from '../../service';
  const myProfile = () => {
  const { user, updateUser } = useUser();
  const [foto, setFoto] = useState(PlaceholderPicture);

useEffect(() => {
   if (user) {
     api
      .get(`/uploads/${user.id}/user-pf.png`)
      .then((response) => {
         console.log('response', response);
         setFoto(response.data);
   })
       .catch((error) => {
             console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
    );
    }
[user]);

...
<img
       className="my-picture"
       src={foto ? foto : PlaceholderPicture}
       alt="Profile"
/>
```

//nodejs

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

I tried converting response.data to binary and use it but it also didn`t work because it doesn't look like it is binary.

I tried also saving the image in the db but it didn't work properly, it was giving me a headache so i did that easier approach but the image is now not displaying correctly.

I don't know what else to do , I tried youtube videos and theyre all similar to my implementation but just here it doesn't work

[image: GET 200]

[image: Image on Preview]

[image: Response.data is broken]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use `axios`, so you could just tell `axios` to fetch image as a [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), and then convert it to URL with [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) and assign it to `img` tag:

```
// change your `api` service to recieve config parameter
    axios
      .get(`/uploads/${user.id}/user-pf.png`, {
            responseType:'blob'
          })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
        setFoto(URL.createObjectURL(response.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
        );
      }
```

or you could simply assign `/uploads/${user.id}/user-pf.png` to `img` tag, as the image is served from public folder

Comment: You sir, are a GOD!
Both solutions worked but the blob one was best fitting, thank you very much!